# Show average values for large amount of data

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I have a MySQL database named WindData which looks like this:

- timestamp
- temperature
- windspeed
- winddirection

I add a new row every 2-3 minutes so over a year time there will be lots of rows.

Now I want to present the data as a chart within a certain timeframe, (4 days ago, last month, last 6 month, 2011-2012...). Say that I want to display how the temperature has varied for the past year, using Google Charts to display this. Then Google chart has a maximum limit of the amount of datapoints that you may use.

I would then like a SQL query where I specify the timerange (2012-01-01  -- 2013-10-10) that gives me

- A fixed number of rows (for example 200)
- Every row contains the average and max value over that interval.

An ascii art example:

```
...............1..............2...............+..............199..............200
```

Where `.` is one row in my table, and the numbers represent average and maxvalue of the previous dots.

Some psudocode that might show what I am trying to accomplish is:

```
SELECT AVG(temperature) 
FROM WindData 
WHERE timestamp > 2012-01-01 AND timestamp < 2013-10-10
```

This would just give me one result where I get the average value of the whole timerange.
So maybe there is a way to create one more SQL statement which runs the above sql statement 200 times with different time-range.

```
SELECT AVG(temperature) 
FROM WindData 
WHERE timestamp > 2012-01-01 AND timestamp < 2013-02-1

SELECT AVG(temperature) 
FROM WindData 
WHERE timestamp > 2012-02-01 AND timestamp < 2013-03-1 

SELECT AVG(temperature) 
FROM WindData 
WHERE timestamp > 2012-03-01 AND timestamp < 2013-04-1

SELECT AVG(temperature) 
FROM WindData 
WHERE timestamp > 2012-04-01 AND timestamp < 2013-05-1
```

...and so on.

If anyone is interested, I will use the help here to present better diagrams on www.surfvind.se, which displays weather data from a homebuilt weather station.

Comment: Can you tell us what you've got so far? Tell us what specific problems you're experiencing.

Comment: Currently I´m using the not so very good solution that I fetch all rows from my c# code and there I calculate all the mean values myself. :-) But obviously that is not a good way, as I then will download ALOT of data from the SQL server every time. I have also tried to run 200 sql queries with different time-range where I ask for the AVG value that I want. But that also does not feel like a good practice either, but maybe that is the best way?

Comment: updated description, to better explain what I want to accomplish.

Comment: Have you managed to optimize your SQL queries? Any results to share? :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computing average values over sections of date/time](/q/940550/90527)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a fixed number of rows using something like this:-

```
SELECT units.i + tens.i * 10 + hundreds.i AS aNumber
FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 ) hundreds
```

You can use something like this to get the different ranges, and join it against you data to get the number of values within each range.

EDIT - To go with the details you have added:-

```
SELECT Sub1.aDate, AVG(temperature)
FROM 
(
    SELECT DATE_ADD('2012-01-01', INTERVAL units.i + tens.i * 10 + hundreds.i * 100 DAY) AS aDate
    FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) hundreds
) Sub1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
WindData
ON Sub1.aDate = DATE(WindData.`timestamp`)
GROUP BY Sub1.aDate
```

This is getting a range of 1000 days starting from 2012-01-01 (you can easily limit that range in the subselect if you want), and matching that against the temp values for a day and getting the average group by date.

Comment: I really have no idea of how this will help me get x average values.

Comment: You need to generate a range of bands. Code like the above can give you a range of values (that gives you 0 to 199). Normally I would use something like that to add to the start date as a number of days. Then match that against the fields you want to check. I will knock something up to go with the details you have added since the original post.

Comment: This is just not correct. :) The sqlserver aborts  the query after some 30 sec of loading. And I´m not so fond of the approach. A better way would be if I could: a) calculate the amount of rows between the two initial dates. b) Divide the result from 'a' with 200 and then either create a for-loop that runs a simple select avg(temperature) between the 200 new dates.

Comment: Looping around selects tends to be hideously slow. The above query should be pretty quick, although it is a pain that it is having to convert the timestamp to a date and time. It could be modified to come up with 200 ranges of date / time stamps fairly easily although then you are going to have some pretty weird start and end dates.